# MVC model structure flat hierarchy

Tags: model-view-controller, model, hierarchy

I got a problem concerning the possible hierarchy of models in a MVC-pattern.

Consider the following situation:

The database have three tables.
Gallery
Album
Image

The gallery has 0..* albums
The album has 0..* images

I also got one model for each table, hence three models. The question is; should I got with a flat structure or a deep structure.

If I want to rename an image we got the following to code snippets.

Deep structure were the hierarchy between models are taken into consideration.

```
public function RenameImage($intAlbumId, $intImageId, $strNewName)
{
    $objGallery = new Gallery();
    $objGallery ->LoadByInput($intPackageId);
    $objAlbum   = $objGallery->GetAlbum($intAlbumId);
    $objImage   = $objAlbum->GetImage($intImageId);

    $objImage   ->SetName($strNewName);
    $objImage   ->Save();
}
```

Or the flat structure:

```
public function RenameImage($intImageId, $strNewName)
{
    $objImage   = new Image();
    $objImage   ->LoadById($intImageId);
    $objImage   ->SetName($strNewName);
    $objImage   ->Save();
}
```

The deep structure will create more code but also more dependencies and a better security were you cant access a model without going through the parent model.

The flat structure will create less code but also lack on the security part.

How would you do it?